# R- How to test multiple 100s of similar variables against a condition

Tags: r

I have a database where some people have multiple diagnoses.

```
ID dx1 dx2 dx3 dx4 dx5 dx6 .... dx200
1  343 432 873 129 12  123       3445
2  34  12  44
3  12 
4  34  56
```

Basically, I want to be able to create a new variable if any of the "dxs" equals a certain number

Is there a quick way in R to scan all dx variables without using hundreds of if statements? All the different variables have the same format (dx#).

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Do you want to select the columns with specific numbers and compute a new variable based on the selected columns?

Comment: So basically,  if any dx code from dx1 - dx200 = 12 for example, the value for the a new variable, lets say "High blood pressure" = 1

Comment: What do you mean by " a database". Is it a text file? Or some SQL database? Or what?

Comment: Its a SAS file that I imported into R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `base` R solution:

```
# toy data set similar to yours, but slightly different
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:4,
  dx1 = c(343, 34, 12, 34),
  dx2 = c(432, 12, 15, 56),
  dx3 = 20:23,
  dx4 = c(12, 9, 9, 9),
  dx5 = 30:33
)

df$highBP <- rowSums(df[, -1] == 12) > 0
```

The logic is: `rowSums(df == 12)` will scan along each row and count the number of entries that are equal to 12. By adding the `> 0` to the end of it, we will collapse that count down to either 1 (if there was at least 1 entry) or 0.

Note that the `[, -1]` is to strip out the first column (so that patient number 12 doesn't get misdiagnosed). In a richer data frame, you'll want to be more careful about the columns you select in that fashion.