# R - Using Stringr to identify a string across hundreds of rows

Tags: r, stringr

I have a database where some people have multiple diagnoses. I posted a similar question in the past, but now have some more nuances I need to work through:

[R- How to test multiple 100s of similar variables against a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617069/r-how-to-test-multiple-100s-of-similar-variables-against-a-condition?noredirect=1#comment110734483_62617069)

I have this dataset (which was an import of a SAS file)

```
ID dx1  dx2  dx3  dx4  dx5  dx6 .... dx200
1  343  432  873  129  12   123       3445
2  34   12   44
3  12 
4  34   56
```

Initially, I wanted to be able to create a new variable if any of the "dxs" equals a certain number without using hundreds of if statements? All the different variables have the same format (dx#). So I used the following code:

Ex:

```
dataset$highbloodpressure  <- rowSums(screen[0:832] == "410") > 0
```

This worked great. However, there are many different codes for the same diagnosis. For example, a heart attack can be defined as:

410.1,
410.71,
410.62,
410.42,
...this goes on for 20 additional codes. BUT! They all start with 410.

I thought about using stringr (the variable is a string), to identify the common code components (410, for the example above), but am not sure how to use it in the context of rowsums.

If anyone has any suggestions for this, please let me know!

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `grepl()` function that returns `TRUE` if a value is present. In order to check all columns simultaneously, just collapse all of them to one character per row:

```
df$dx.410 = NA
for(i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  if(grepl('410',paste(df[i,2:200],collapse=' '))){
    df$dx.410[i]="Present"
  }
}
```

This will loop through all lines, create one large character containing all diagnoses for this case and write "Present" in column `dx.410` if any column contains a 410-diagnosis.

(The solution expects the data structure you have here with the dx-variables in columns 2 to 200. If there are some other columns, just adjust these numbers)

Comment: This works great! Is there a way to test for multiple patterns?
For example, create a "present" if its 410 OR 412 etc.